# What is the order of events for working with OPOS compatible hardware?

Tags: c#, opos, pos-for-.net

I am working with a OPOS compatible MSR.  Is the order of events:

1. Open
2. Claim
3. Enable
4. Release
5. Close

Answer (score 5):

Technically, it's `Open()` / `ClaimDevice()` / `DeviceEnabled` = TRUE / `DeviceEnabled` = FALSE / `ReleaseDevice()` / `Close()`.

`Open()` requests a handle to the named device, and should work if the device exists.  `Close()` is the matching pair function, and it should be called when the device is no longer needed by the application.

`ClaimDevice()` (previously known as the `Claim()` method) will attempt to access the device.  If the device is an exclusive-use device (such as a barcode scanner), `ClaimDevice()` will fail if a different process has already claimed it.  `ReleaseDevice()` (also known as `Release()` but it's name conflicted with the COM method `Release()`) is the matching pair function that should be called when the application no longer needs to access the device. This enables graceful sharing of devices between applications.  An example might be if you have a button on your sales application to enter the inventory application - the sales application should call `ReleaseDevice()` on the scanner so the inventory application can successfully call `ClaimDevice()`.

Setting `DeviceEnable` to TRUE will make the device ready for input.  If it's a barcode scanner, it would turn on the laser.  Only an enabled device will fire `DataEvent()`s.  You would generally set the barcode scanner to true when you are ready to accept barcodes, then set it to false if the barcode was in error and you wanted them to stop scanning.

Technically, you don't have to set `DeviceEnable` to false prior to calling `ReleaseDevice()`; and you don't even have to call `ReleaseDevice()` prior to calling `Close()`.  OPOS is like a neurotic maid, and will clean those up even if the application doesn't.  However, I personally think it's evidence of sloppy programming if devices aren't managed properly.

Comment: I am making use of an OPOS scanner in my program. When the program closes I disable, release and close the device, but no other application can use it after my program runs. Also if I restart no application can use it. Not even my application which causes the issue. Any idea?

Comment: @Chris-HaddoxTechnologies This is an old question/comment, but did you ever figure out your issue Chris? Running into a potentially similar issue myself.

Comment: Its been a long time. I believe my issue was incorrectly handled threads accessing the scanner at the same time. Its been a long time since I had to mess with those scanners.